# WTForms-How to prepopulate a textarea field?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Hi I have been trying to pepopulate a textareafield using something
like this in the template.

```
{{form.content(value="please type content")}}
```

This works when the field is textfield primarily because the html
accepts value for `<input type="text">`
but the same does not work for textarea...
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Alice, what is `form` in this context -- is it a `WTForms.Form` object or is it something else?

Comment: It is a WTForms.Form object Sean!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For `textarea` widgets, you set the default content with the `default` argument in your field constructors.

```
class YourForm(Form):
    your_text_area = TextAreaField("TextArea", default="please add content")
```

Then when you render:

```
{{form.content()}}
```

WTForms will render the default text.  I have not been able to find a way to specify default text for the text area at render time.

Comment: Thanks Sean! But I need to do it in the template. It is something like an edit blog link.When you click the edit button against any blog, it should present a form with the title in the textfield(which is done using the value parameter) and the content of the blog in the textarea field.

Comment: Hi ,The form defintion, the view function and the html of the form can be viewed here:-
http://pastebin.com/QC4MC84B

Comment: `<script> var textarea = document.getElementById('yourIDHere'); textarea.innerHTML = "{{ your_text_variable }}" </script>`

Answer (score 38):

You can do it before rendering, something like:

```
form.content.data = 'please type content'
```

I'm new to WTForms though.

Comment: That's what I wanted

Comment: When I do this any data submitted is not recorded.

Comment: @thosphor and to anyone seeing this later, it's probably because the line is executed both for GET and POST requests. So, when doing a POST request, the data is overwritten with the "default" content you wanted. To fix this, just put the line in a 'if' block like so : `if request.method == 'GET': form.content.data = 'please type content'`

Answer (score 20):

I recently had the same problem, I solved it like this:

```
{% set f = form.content.process_data("please type content") %}
{{ form.content() }}
```

For a test, you can try run the follow snippet:

```
>>> import wtforms
>>> import jinja2
>>> from wtforms.fields import TextAreaField
>>> class MyForm(wtforms.Form):
...     content = TextAreaField("Text Area")
... 
>>> t = jinja2.Template("""{% set f = form.content.process_data("please type content") %}
...                     {{ form.content() }}""")
>>> 
>>> t.render(form=MyForm())
u'\n                    <textarea id="content" name="content">please type content</textarea>'
```

Comment: This does the trick, though there's a teeny problem. I'm not sure if I did anything wrong. Unfortunately `process_data()` prints a `None` on the HTML, besides that, it's golden.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't read the tags of the post when I wrote the answer. I posted the solution using the Tornado template module, however, I've updated the answer using Jinja2.

Comment: This worked better than the above solutions for me because it allows for variable content.

Comment: Thank you for this!! I also applied it to my SelectField and it works perfectly! You've saved me hours!

Comment: This worked for me especially because I wanted to assign the value dynamically in the template.

Answer (score 7):

For those trying to do this dynamically ***in*** jinja template, setting the default value prior to rendering does not fix this problem.

Instead of using the WTForms standard:

```
{{ form.content() }}
```

You can construct this element with raw HTML like:

```
<textarea id="FormName-content" name="FormName-content">{{ dynamic values here }}</textarea>
```

...and it will still work with your WTForms validation.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Upvoting you because this is exactly what I have had to do, but I do think this is a really stupid solution! Why can't WTForms handle TextArea fields in a similar manner to how they handle regular text inputs??? Does no-one ever update text in a TextArea field???

Answer (score 6):

Alice there seems to be support built into the form widget to do what you are after but you are right it doesn't work at the moment.

Sean and hilquias post decent work arounds which do work. This is the form (yuk yuk) you might try

```
 else:
        form.title.data=blog.title
        form.blogdata.data=blog.blogdata
    return render_template('editblog.html',form=form)
```

Answer (score 5):

Define your form with the `TextArea` field

```
class MyForm(Form):
    name = fields.StringField('Name', validators=[Required()])
    description = fields.TextAreaField('Description')
```

Set the textarea content before rending the template

```
form = MyForm()
form.description.data='this is my textarea content!' # This is the stuff...
return render_template('form.html', form=form, name=name)
```

Render the fields in your template

```
<form ...>
    {{ field(form.name, value=name) }}
    {{ field(form.description, rows=2) }}
    <button ...>Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

This thread is a bit old but if you need to prepopulate the textarea field with dynamic content, you could use setattr and the *default* parameter like so:

```
if post.content:

    form = EditPostForm
    setattr(form, "content", TextAreaField(gettext('Post content'), validators=[Length(max=5000)], default=post.content))
    form = EditPostForm()

else:
    form = EditPostForm()
```

Don't forget to import TextAreaField.

Comment: This is the best answer! No other solution worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This works! Thanks!  ( gettext('Post content') is actually not needed )

Answer (score 4):

You can also pre-populate a textarea field by passing it in to your WTforms class instantiation in render_template (in this example I'm using the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) framework):

```
@admin.route('/edit/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(id):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProspectForm(request.form)
    prospect = Prospect.objects(id=id).first()
    return render_template('admin/edit.html', prospect=prospect, prospect_form=ProspectForm(comments = prospect.comments))
```

So, **comments=prospect.comments** says "set the text inside the [TextAreaField](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.TextAreaField) field named 'comments' to the data contained in prospect.comments"

Answer (score -7):

In a Textarea you will need to use innerHTML or html() if you use jquery.

in your context should be:

```
form.content.innerHTML = "please type content";

//using jquery
$('#element').html("please type content");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: WTForms is a server-side Python library for rendering form HTML -- jQuery will not help in this context unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out though!