# Form data not submitted when textarea already filled

Tags: python, html, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm using WTForms and Jinja2 to make a page with an editable textarea. The idea is to edit text in a database, so the textarea should already be populated with text for the user to edit.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117479/wtforms-how-to-prepopulate-a-textarea-field#5175227)/answer I have something like the 
following code:
In `app.py`:

```
form = MyForm() # MyForm is defined elsewhere simply as 
                # class MyForm(FlaskForm): content=TextAreaField()
prepopulated = GetTextFromDatabase()
form.content.data = prepopulated

if form.validate_on_submit():
    new_content = form.content.data
    SaveToDatabase(new_content)

return flask.render_template('edit.html', form=form)
```

In `edit.html`:

```
<form method="POST">
  <div>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.content }}
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

However, when submitting, the changes made to the text are not saved in the database. If I remove the `form.content.data = prepopulated` the changes are saved.

So how can I prepopulate the textarea yet make sure any changes to the text are saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared the code for your `MyForm` which would have been helpful since the accepted answer in the link you posted advised of using the `default` argument in form creation step.

The reason this is not working is because if a user `POSTS` a form to your route than all you do is **overwrite the data** before you validate the form with this code:

```
prepopulated = GetTextFromDatabase()
form.content.data = prepopulated
```

Instead why not try validating the form data first and executing your database save like this:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    new_content = form.content.data
    SaveToDatabase(new_content)
else:
    prepopulated = GetTextFromDatabase()
    form.content.data = prepopulated

return flask.render_template('edit.html', form=form)
```

Comment: "since the accepted answer in the link you posted advised of using the default argument in form creation step" - I added the definition of my form in the question. I didn't see how default argument was relevant since you can't set it dynamically. Anyway, your solution worked. I had thought having the `form.content.data = prepopulated` outside the `if form.validate():` would be enough to prevent the overwrite.

Comment: There are ways to set the default dynamically if thats what is needed. Either wrap the form creation up in a function (searching dynamic wtforms will yield lots of results). Or in the __init__ method of the form use super().__init__() first and then set your values.